# Retrieving recent comments for multiple posts through FQL or graph API - Inconsistent results

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-comments

We are trying to poll recent comments for a fb page. It appears that using graph API requires a separate call per post (e.g if there are 100 posts we'll have to do 100 calls to retrieve the comments of all posts).

So, we're using FQL in the following way:

```
    https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=json&access_token<acess_token>&query=SELECT id, text, post_id, fromid, username, time, likes FROM comment WHERE post_id in ('156790397738497_357582840992584', ...)
```

Most of the time it works fine, but we've found several cases where it does not return all the comments of a post (using the graph API for the specific post id does retrieve all posts).

Has anyone found any solution to this or a better way to retrieve all recent comments of a page?

We've filled a FB bug (http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/529168040436289) but they don't seem to be willing to investigate it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a major problem for us too. This really should work. Slightly disappointing that something as important as this is not supported by FB.